# unable to naviate data structure in ansible using with_subelements

Tags: ansible

Can someone please explain why this code does not work? I want to expand it to a larger dataset, but I can't get this simple version working. It looks the same as an example I found to me.

```
      1 ---
      2
      3 - hosts: localhost
      4   vars:
      5     GENERAL:
      6       - CE_HOSTNAME: ROUTER1
      7         CE_NEW: true
      8
      9   tasks:
     10
     11     - debug: debug
     12         msg: "{{ item.0.CE_HOSTNAME }}"
     13       with_subelements:
     14         - "{{ GENERAL }}"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no sublists (nested lists) in the list *GENERAL*. [with_subelements](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/subelements_lookup.html#ansible-builtin-subelements-traverse-nested-key-from-a-list-of-dictionaries) can't work here. Use simple loop instead. For example,

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    GENERAL:
      - CE_HOSTNAME: ROUTER1
        CE_NEW: true
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: item
      loop: "{{ GENERAL }}"
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
  item:
    CE_HOSTNAME: ROUTER1
    CE_NEW: true
```

*with_subelements* can be used if there are nested lists. For example

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    GENERAL:
      - CE_HOSTNAME: ROUTER1
        CE_NEW: true
        CE_LIST:
          - item1
          - item2
          - item3
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: item
      with_subelements:
        - "{{ GENERAL }}"
        - CE_LIST
```

gives the product of the lists (abridged)

```yaml
  item:
  - CE_HOSTNAME: ROUTER1
    CE_NEW: true
  - item1

  item:
  - CE_HOSTNAME: ROUTER1
    CE_NEW: true
  - item2

  item:
  - CE_HOSTNAME: ROUTER1
    CE_NEW: true
  - item3
```